# How to repeat a backround image for listview

Tags: android

I have dynamic no of list items to display in a `ListView`.
I am using a background image (fixed height).

I want to repeat this image when list items are too many.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the background in your activity (android:background="@drawable/background") and then let the list scroll "over" it?
And then set the CacheColorHint of the ListView to #0000 (android:cacheColorHint="#0000")

Comment: This is working fine. But i need Background repeat image to move along with list view content.